# Why does meteorite take so long to load? 1.2 MB

Tags: performance, dictionary, load, meteor, meteorite

Why does the first load of my meteorite site take so long to load? (www.jasperlu.com). It seems like most of the loading time is being taken up loading .map files or sockets. Is there a way to speed this up tremendously?

Answer (score 0):

You're not using your site in production mode. Remember you should bundle your project up and not just use `meteor` to get it running. Using `meteor` is for development only.

See https://www.eventedmind.com/feed/okpzbuNSspDf6tPiy for a screencast on how to do this step by step.